# Custom bulleted text in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring, custom-font

I need square bulleted(colored) text as follows

```
◼︎ Some large amount of text that    
  make it span to the next line.
```

to be shown in `UITextView`. But the problem is it doesn't git the padding on the next line.

> ◼︎ Some large amount of text that
>         make it span to the next line.

These bulleted text is of static content and hence no need to set it through code. 
Also custom font is not working when I set attributed type. Custom font used is `Raleway`.

Comment: You could use `NSParagraphAttributeName` to handle the indent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a ruler with a "hanging indent." I have no idea how to do this manually with text attributes.

I would suggest instead setting up what you want in a `.rtf` file and then loading an attributed string from the RTF using either `initWithURL:options:documentAttributes:error:` (which is only available in iOS 9 or later) or `initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:` (which is available in iOS >= 7.0.)

You specify an options dictionary of

Objective-C:

```
@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType}
```

Swift:

```
[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType]
```